# On hover target next element in loop ( map ) ? using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using React and i want to solve problem with React solution.

I need on hover to target next element.

All code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-list-sample-map-with-keys-forked-35zubq?file=/src/styles.css:59-210

What I need example:

if you hover on element with number 3 i want to remove border-top from element 4
if you hover on element with number 4 i want to remove border-top from element 5

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map(number => (
  <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>
));

export default function App() {
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}


ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

ul li:hover {
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

I don't have a idea how to do it.

I googled and every solution is a solution in jQuery

Comment: I don't think that you can achieve that inside CSS. You should try using useState hook and finding a solution for that

Comment: I agree, it can't be done with css, but how about a hook. to do that ?

Comment: I'm working on a demo and I'll update you in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to handle that with the `adjacent sibling` combinator:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map(number => (
  <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>
));

export default function App() {
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}


ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

ul li:hover + li {
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

`li:hover + li` will select the adjacent sibling to the one you're hovering. If you hover over `<li>3</li>`, `ul li:hover + li` will select `<li>4</li>` and so on.

Comment: I guess this one can work @Cinovates